# File extension issue

Tags: gcc, find, file-format

usually when I compile a  C program I give the command:

```
gcc -o program_name program_name.c
```

I have a folder full of program_name and program_name.c files.

I wanted to delete the program_name files. So I looked around and found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/recursively-delete-all-files-with-a-given-extension), which suggest to use the "find" command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.o' -exec rm {} +
```

Problem is that it requires the file extension to work and this files don't have one.

I can't even find them:

```
find -type f -name '*.out'

find -type f -name '*.o'
```

give no results.

`ls -l`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8432 date & time addressof
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8480 date & time addressof2
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  544 date & time addressof2.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  128 date & time addressof.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8480 date & time char_array
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  390 date & time char_array.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8424 date & time commandline
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  202 date & time commandline.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8536 date & time convert
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8536 date & time convert2
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  366 date & time convert2.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  359 date & time convert.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8424 date & time datatype_size
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  532 date & time datatype_size.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8424 date & time firstprog
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  108 date & time firstprog.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8480 date & time fmt_strings
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  398 date & time fmt_strings.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8520 date & time input
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  307 date & time input.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8776 date & time memory_segments
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username 1641 date & time memory_segments.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8472 date & time pointer
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  404 date & time pointer.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8472 date & time pointers
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  601 date & time pointers.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8520 date & time pointer_types
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8520 date & time pointer_types2
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  757 date & time pointer_types2.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8520 date & time pointer_types3
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username 1303 date & time pointer_types3.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8520 date & time pointer_types4
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username 1002 date & time pointer_types4.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8520 date & time pointer_types5
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  943 date & time pointer_types5.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  682 date & time pointer_types.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8512 date & time scope
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8584 date & time scope2
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  688 date & time scope2.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8640 date & time scope3
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username 1013 date & time scope3.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  543 date & time scope.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8432 date & time sizeof_pointer
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  199 date & time sizeof_pointer.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8472 date & time stack_example
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  178 date & time stack_example.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8544 date & time static
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8632 date & time static2
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  433 date & time static2.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  334 date & time static.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8528 date & time strtol_function
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  423 date & time strtol_function.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8424 date & time typecasting
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  308 date & time typecasting.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_username 8480 date & time wrong_pointer
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_username  600 date & time wrong_pointer.c
```

Comment: Tried, doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `ls -l` in the directory in a code block.

Comment: `find -type f \! -name '*.c'` should do the trick.

Comment: Ding ding ding !! you are the winner. I think it also works without the '\'

Comment: Glad to hear that, I added it as an answer below. You're right `!` doesn't need to be escaped, I just wonder why it is in `find`'s manpage…

Comment: Instead of `-exec rm {} +` you can just use `-delete` by the way. Use both with care!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find -type f ! -name '*.c'
```

finds every `f`ile whose file `name` is **not** (`!`) ending in `.c`.

To play it safe, either use `-ok` instead of `-exec` **or** execute `rm` with the `-i` option:

```
find -type f ! -name '*.c' -ok rm {} +
find -type f ! -name '*.c' -exec rm -i {} +
```

If you're absolutely sure you can automatically delete all findings with `-delete` (always as the last option!) instead of calling another program:

```
find -type f ! -name '*.c' -delete
```

As always: **Backup your data and delete with care**.